# I would like to process semi-structured text. Can machine learning be used?

Tags: machine-learning

I have many emails that I would like to extract data from. The emails contain data but in different formats.

The below example contains data about a request for a shipment:

```
Account: SugarHigh Inc
Qty: 1,000 Tons Sugar
Date: 9 - 15 July
From: NY
To: IL
```

I would like to extract the above into the following format:

```
Account        Quantity     Product     FromDate     ToDate     From     To
-------        --------     -------     --------     ------     ----     --
SugarHigh Inc  1000         Sugar       9 July       15 July    NY       IL
```

The same request can arrive in a different formats.For example:

```
Acc: SugarHigh Inc
Qty/Date: 1,000 Tons Sugar/9 - 15 July
From/To: NY/IL
```

Some requests can even have more or less fields or describe things differently.

Can machine learning be used in assisting to extract this data fully/partially? If so what type of algorithms/models exist for this type of problem? I am assuming I might also need to use some type of dictionary for known words such as products or locations.

Comment: @LukaszTacewski provided a good response. Machine learning has many adaptable fields. It depends on what type of network you wish to pursue, you will have to decide on this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, you start with reading [this post on text mining](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35249/machine-learning-techniques-for-parsing-strings). That being said, I'd recommend just using some (fuzzy) string searching. The variability in such data is limited. Every time you encounter new pattern just add it to the algorithm. Should yield you better results and cost less time.